# How to check condition and print a value using views-view-field--viewname.tpl.php?

Tags: views, theming

I'm having a view and I've created a template file for the row style output.
I'm able to access the fields using the below code:

```
$fields: An array of $field objects. Each one contains:
$field->content: The output of the field.
$field->raw: The raw data for the field, if it exists. This is NOT output safe.
```

I'm getting output for the below code:

```
<?php print $fields['field_some_field_name']->content; ?>
```

But when I'm trying to print the fields nothing is getting returned:

```
<?php print_r($fields); ?>
```

I'm also unable to check the condition for the fields:

```
<?php if($fields['field_some_field_name']->content == 'Test') { } ?>
```

Comment: Enable this module https://www.drupal.org/project/devel and then instead of print_r use dpm(); and don't use die or exit functions.

Comment: Is the template loaded or not? Did you clear cache after adding the template?

Comment: @JimmyKo Yes I cleared cache after doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm also unable to check the condition for the fields:
>
> ```
> <?php if($fields['field_some_field_name']->content == 'Test') { } ?>
> ```

That is probably because in actuality:

`$fields['field_some_field_name']->content` = `<div>Test</div>`

Therefore, `<div>Test</div>` is not equal to `Test`

So what you could do is use `raw` instead, as `raw` has no html/markup around the value.

```
<?php if($fields['field_some_field_name']->raw == 'Test') { } ?>
```

else, you could still use `content` with the PHP [striptags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function

```
<?php if(striptags($fields['field_some_field_name']->content) == 'Test') { } ?>
```

Or else, you could still use your original `<?php print $fields['field_some_field_name']->content; ?>` but as long as you strip all the markup added by views as shown in my answer to "[Is there a more performant alternative than overriding template files?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207740/is-there-a-more-performant-alternative-than-overriding-template-files/207741#207741)".