# Theming views fields with twig

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have a search results view from Search API where I need to use the excerpt that highlights the keywords being searched. In this instance, that prevents me from using a view mode output as the result.

In this instance, I have a view set up to output title, URI, date modified and search excerpt. I have a decent bit of theming to do around the form and results, but I can't seem to figure out how to view both the template suggestions for each view field, or just theme it manually in the given template `views-view--unformatted--search--results.html.twig`.

I also tried `{{ kint(row) }}` and even when viewing on its own page, basically locked up my browser.

So for instance, for the title, I need the markup to be:

`<a href="#" class="search-result__item-title">Foo Exam</a>`

For consistency reasons, I would like to control it from twig templates instead of attempt to do it in the views admin (setting label field etc settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for

views-view-fields--[view-name]--[machine-name].html.twig

views-view-fields--search--results.html.twig

In your view click on your title field and uncheck `Link to the content`.

then your template file

```
<a href="#" class="search-result__item-title">{{ fields.title.content }}</a>
```

Not really sure if you really want `#` as `href`. I think you want to link to content. So add `Path` as a field.

```
<a href="{{ fields.path.content }}" class="search-result__item-title">{{ fields.title.content|striptags }}</a>
```

**Note:** You'll probably want to use `|striptags` if you do not [strip the markup from the views UI](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207740/is-there-a-more-performant-alternative-than-overriding-template-files/207741#207741). Unless you do not mind having `<divs>` wrapping your title text.

then `{{ fields.field_machine_name.content }}` each of the rest of your fields that you want to output.

> **Important**: Make sure TWIG DEBUG is off, as it tends to screw up templates in Views.

Comment: Yeah the # is just from the prototype.

Comment: How do I find out what the machine name would be for just the node title? `title` by itself does not work.

Comment: In content type Manage Display, there is a [Machine Name column](https://www.drupal.org/files/field-ui-machine-name.png), you can check there. But... the machine name should be `title`, unless you somehow changed it... Oh also check that you're not hiding this field from display in the Views UI.

Comment: Yes. Also, fields.path.content doesn't work. This data is coming out of Search API + Search API Solr.

Comment: @Kevin interesting, if you do a Rewrite Results on your title field throught the Views Field UI, for available replacement patterns what do you get?

Comment: It just says `{{ title }}`. I just printed the excerpt as `{{ fields.search_result_excerpt.content }}`.

Comment: So are you saying that twig level overrides per field is not possible in views?

Comment: @Kevin, I guess you could use views-view-field--title--[view-name].html.twig

Comment: @Kevin nvm because you need access to the `path` field along with your `title`. That's why we are not using it here.

Comment: @Kevin do you have Twig Debug on? that tends to screw up templates in views. Turn it off and flush cache if you do.