# Conditionally output by content type using Twig

Tags: views, 8

I want to theme the display of a Views based on the Content type. In my attempts to do that, I’ve created the views showing All Content Types. I’ve added all the fields I need, and also included a Content: Type field. It is this field that I am trying to use for conditionally formatting the output (if it’s a Blog content type use this html and for all other content types use a different html).

This is what I have tried so far but that condition is not triggering at all

I have created a views-view-fields--myexample.html.twig

```
{% if fields.type.content == 'blog' %}
<div class="blog-content views-row">
  <div class="showcase" style="background-color: {{ fields.field_color.content }};">

</div>
{% else %}

<div class="other-content views-row">
   <div class="showcase">
   {{ fields.title.content}}
   {{ fields.field_image.content }}
   </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because `{{ fields.type.content }}` = `<div class="something">blog</div>`

so try

```
{% if fields.type.content|striptags == {{ 'blog'|t }} %}
```

If you do not want to have to use `|striptags` you could [strip the markup from the Views UI](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207740/is-there-a-more-performant-alternative-than-overriding-template-files/207741#207741).

Also, do not check mark `Exclude from display` in configure field, because if you do this your template file will not have access to that field.

Side note: you forgot to close the div in line 3.

---

Alternatively

```
{% if row._entity.gettype == 'content_type_machine_name' %}
```

<sub>alternate method credit: [4K4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226651/conditionally-output-by-content-type-using-twig/226653?noredirect=1#comment-276899)</sub>

Comment: Good advice for fields in general. For the content type there is an alternative option, you can get the id directly from the entity: `{{ row._entity.gettype }}`. Then you don't depend on that the field is configured correctly in UI (what if it gets translated?).

Comment: @4k4, good point, updated my answer to cover for translations.