# Simple Twig conditional not behaving as expected with webform_views

Tags: views, 8, webforms

I have a webform with a Checkbox (i.e. boolean) field called 'Paid'; I'm using webform_views to include and rewrite it in a view (there's some extra code which adds a link to the payment page, but I've stripped that out for these purposes.)

**Replacement Pattern section:**  {{ webform_submission_value_1 }} == Paid

**Format:** set to raw value (i.e. 0 or 1 rather than Yes/No)

**Twig:** (in 'Override the output of this field with custom text')

```
Value: {{ webform_submission_value_1 }}

Conditional: 

{% if webform_submission_value_1 == 1 %}
  paid
{% else %}
  not paid
{% endif %}
```

**Output:**

> Value: 0   Conditional: paid

and if edit the form and toggle the value:

> Value: 1 Conditional: paid

**NB:** the view is more complicated that this and there are other fields, but they all seem to behaving correctly. Also there are access restrictions on the *Paid* field for non-administrators, but even with these on the View seems to be able to display the value correctly.

Comment: try `{% if webform_submission_value_1|strip_tags == 1 %}`

Comment: @NoSssweat still the same...

Comment: @NoSssweat aha - just noticed I was getting an XHR error when updating the preview  - `striptags` without the underscore works. Thank you!

Comment: yeah my bad, the twig version doesn't have underscore. Alternatively if you don't want to have to use `striptags` you could [uncheck some settings in Views UI](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207740/is-there-a-more-performant-alternative-than-overriding-template-files/207741#207741). Can't remember if screenshot 1 alone will do, if not, also do screenshot 3.