# How Print individual fields in a view row by row

Tags: views, 8, theming

I have so much fields in a content like "title", "field_image", "field_description", and i use a view for create a block and put it on my front page...

I will make a slider with a jquery plugin (jssor slider), i need use the structure of jssor slider. then in my view, i use "views-view-fields--[name_machine]--block.html.twig" for print individual fields. but the file "views-view-fields..." print for each content, run all code on this file,and i need to put the initial containers of this plugin only once, and the code of the images several times.

I try to put the initial containers of the plugin in the "page.html.twig" but when i print the block with the "views-view-fields..." inside
he puts a lot of code and many labels and containers that I do not need and the plugin stops working. let me show the files.

my page.html.twig
          {# Header #}
      {% if page.banner_front %}

```
    <div id="jssor_1">
      <!-- Loading Screen -->
      <div data-u="loading" class="jssorl-009-spin">
          <img src="/images/spin.svg" />
      </div>
      <div data-u="slides"> 

        {% block banner_front %}
            {{ page.banner_front }}
        {% endblock %}

      </div>       
     </div>
```

then my views-view-fields--banner--block.html.twig:

```
           <div data-b="0">
                <img data-u="image" src="{{ fields.field_imagen.content }}"/>
                <div class="caption-banner" data-u="caption" data-t="0">
                    <div class="title-banner">
                        {% if fields.title.content %}
                            {{ fields.title.content }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="description-banner">
                        {% if fields.banner_description.content %}
                            {{ fields.banner_description.content }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    {% if fields.field_url.content %}
                        <a href="#" target="_blan">   
                            <div class="btn-ver">Ver más</div>
                        </a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

to work correctly, the label `<div data-b = '0'>` must be left of the label `<div data-u = 'slides'>`, but when the region is printed the system prints many labels and containers that damage the structure of the slider.

On Drupal 7 i used inside of the foreach the code of the images, and outside the inicial structure, and works well but now, i dont know how to this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `the "views-view-fields..." inside he puts a lot of code and many labels and containers that I do not need` to remove this markup [follow my answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207740/is-there-a-more-performant-alternative-than-overriding-template-files/207741#207741)

Comment: if you work with `Format:Unformatted list` try to override the `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` you will have the ability to add class to parent or inside each row

Comment: so glad that help.

Comment: I have poste it as answer if someone need it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with **Format:Unformatted list** try to override the `views-view-unformatted.html.twig`, you will have the ability to add class to parent or inside each row.